# R - non-exported functions still exposed to the user

Tags: r, namespaces, package, dependencies

I'm putting some R code together in a package, and struggling with namespace + import/export problems. It seems that whether or not I add an `#' @export` line in roxygen, the functions are still visible to the user. So if I have this file:

```
#' Function I want the user to see
#'
#' A description
#'
#' @param X a parameter
#' @return the same thing
#' @export
external_function<-function(X){X}
#' Function I don't want the user to see
#'
#' A description
#'
#' @param X a parameter
#' @return the same thing
internal_function<-function(X){X}
```

both functions end up being exposed, along with `library.dynam.unload` and `system.file`:

[image]

It doesn't seem to make any difference whether the functions are in separate files or not - even if all the functions that shouldn't be exposed are in one file, without any that should, they're still appearing.

Relatedly, all functions from other packages which I import are appearing - I don't know whether this is intended behaviour (it certainly isn't what I wanted!) or whether this is part of the same issue.

```
#' Function I want the user to see
#'
#' A description
#'
#' @param X a parameter
#' @return the same thing
#' @importFrom dplyr %>%
#' @export
external_function<-function(X){X %>% log}
```

with this line in the DESCRIPTION file:

```
Imports:
  dplyr
```

results in:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to use functions internally without them being exposed to the user?

Comment: Have you by chance used `devtools::load_all` in your development of this package? If you've used it before in the current R environment, I think you can `detach("package:testpackage", unload=TRUE, force=TRUE)` and try to load the package the non-`devtools` way. If that doesn't work, try restarting R into a fresh instance (no `.Rdata` file) and try again. (Read `?load_all`, specifically about `export_all=`.)

Comment: What matters is what is in your `NAMESPACE` file.  It may be it is not being written by roxygen.

Comment: thank you both! it turns out that the problem was indeed with devtools::load_all, and clearing the the environment and loading it without using devtools (or with devtools::load_all(...,export_all=F) shows only what i thought i was exporting! :))

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with the way I'd loaded the package, using `devtools::load_all()`. Using `devtools::load_all(...,export_all=F)` or loading the package without devtools means that only the right functions are exported :).